# when attempting to render results page on form submission, blank html document is shown

Tags: html, go, web-frameworks

The code below renders the initial page, which has a form in it. On submission of that form, I want to render a results page. The form submits and is handled, but all I see is a blank html document.

I don't want to only display an html page, but render it as some of the content will come from my golang code on form submission.I am trying to do this using templating ( from a template ) where designated lines in the `<body></body>` are the values of Golang variables.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me figure out how to render a results page.

```
package main


import (
    //"fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/zenazn/goji"
    "github.com/zenazn/goji/web"

    "html/template"
    "io/ioutil"
)


type Page struct {
     Title string
     Body []byte
}


func (p *Page) save() error{
     filename := p.Title + ".txt"
     return ioutil.WriteFile(filename, p.Body, 0600) 
}


func loadPage(title string) (*Page, error){
     filename := title + ".txt"
     body, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
     if err != nil{
          return nil, err
     }
     return &Page{Title: title, Body: body}, nil 
}


func renderTemplate(w http.ResponseWriter, tmpl string, p *Page){
     t, _ := template.ParseFiles("Projects/Go/src/web/site/" + tmpl + ".html")
     t.Execute(w, p) 
}


func editHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
     title := r.URL.Path[len("/edit/"):]
     p, err := loadPage(title)
     if err != nil{
         p = &Page{Title: title}
     }
     renderTemplate(w, "edit", p)
}


func viewHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
     title := r.URL.Path[len("/ask"):]
     p, _ := loadPage(title)
     renderTemplate(w, "ask", p)
}


func response(c web.C, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
     //name := r.FormValue("name")
     //fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, %s!", name)

     http.HandleFunc("/ask", viewHandler)
     http.HandleFunc("/edit/", editHandler)
     //http.HandleFunc("/save", saveHandler)
     http.ListenAndServe("8000", nil)
}


func serveSingle(filename string) func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        http.ServeFile(w, r, filename)
    }
}


func main() {
     goji.Get("/", serveSingle("Projects/Go/src/web/site/index.html"))
     goji.Handle("/ask", response)
     goji.Serve()
}
```

file structure:

root/Projects/Go/src/web/site/edit.html

root/Projects/Go/src/web/site/index.html

root/Projects/Go/src/web/site/view.html

index.html's body:

```
<form action="ask" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="q" />
</form>
```

view.html's body:

```
<form action="ask" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="q" />
</form>
<h1 class="abTitle">{{printf "%s" .Body}}</h1>
```

view.html and edit.html are the exact same.

Comment: `../web/ask` is definitely not what you want: you need somewhere to POST the form to.

Comment: @elithrar how about just ask or ../ask for the action? And then i'll change the method to post. I thought get was for things with a results page and post was for sending data like a contact form though?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. `GET` is fine in this case, but it should be `action="/ask"` - i.e. a route in your application.

Comment: @elithrar I changed it to ask in index.html, view.html, and edit.html as now reflected in the question, but the blank page persists.

Comment: Do the templates have opening/closing `<html>` and `<body>` tags?

Comment: @elithrar yes, they do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59858/discussion-between-elithrar-and-user3743069).

Comment: @elithrar i rewrote the code from scratch following a web app tutorial in the golang documentation. Now on form submission, i am getting an error in chrome that says no data received. May i show you the code?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, the script you published should respond on the `/` requests and crash on requests to the `/ask`. On the request to the `/ask` it should execute the `response` handler and panic (as the documentation specifies http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux.Handle But what exactly will happen is quite unclear. Anyway, it will be more idiomatic (for such small server) to configure all the handlers in advance and avoid registering handlers in responses.

Another issue is in the  `viewHandler` function - it will be called with `/ask` request only, but then the `/ask` will be stripped and the title will be "" - this will lead to loading ".txt" template file, which is probably not intentional.

It will be also helpful if you post the content of your form template and files structure (folders and file names).

Comment: Thank you. I updated the question with the file locations and the html of the files. I hope this helps you help me. Let me know if you need anything else. Thanks in Advance!